# focusout does not work with tabs

Tags: jquery

I have this autoupdate function everytime focus out of input box

```
            $("#input")
                .focusout(function(event) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");           
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        ROWID: rowid,           
                        updateValue: $("#input").val(),
                        updateColumn: column
                        },
                    success: function(data){
                    if (data[0] == "TRUE"){
                    $("#input").removeAttr("disabled");
                            }   
                        }
                    });         
                });
```

In php the SQL execute is

```
update table set $_GET['updateColumn'] = $_GET['updateValue'] where rowid =  $_GET['ROWID']
```

I have this $("#input").removeAttr("disabled"); to feedback saying if the update is success.
But the function seems to escape if I use tab to go to next inputbox. There is no problem if U use box to click. Is there a way to counter this?

Comment: [It works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/924SZ/66/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("form").on("blur", "#input", function() { ... });` instead of `.focusout`

Also, you should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` and `.removeAttr`

example:
`.prop('disabled', true);`

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) gets used for form elements.